# pass URL special characters in XML to curl

Tags: php, xml, curl

I had an XML file with a url variable containing special characters such as &, = etc

I have two questions:

A. Since the special characters are not allowed in XML, how should I enter the URL? Should I encode the url and then put in XML file?

B. Assuming that I encode the url and put it in XML file and then read in a php script.

```
$fxml = simplexml_load_file("mylist.xml");
$fxml -> getName();

foreach($fxml->children() as $mylist)
    {
        $url = $mylist -> url;
        $url = urldecode(url);
        echo $url;

        $feed = curl_init( $url );
        curl_setopt($feed, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($feed, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        $xml = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($feed));

        curl_close($feed);
        //---------------------
        //---------------------
 }
```

Here is the sample XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <feed>
        <mylist>
            <name>                                                                                                                                                                                    
             SISC                                                                                                                                                                                    
            </name>
            <url>                                                                                                                                                                                     
             http://epubs.siam.org/action/showFeed?ui=0&amp;mi=3chvf9&amp;ai=s0&amp;jc=sjnaam&amp;type=etoc&amp;feed=rss                                                                               
            </url>
        </mylist>
    </feed>
```

Notice that I have replaced the URL in encoded form where original & is replaced by its code. I also tried not using urldecode but I only get echo $url correctly.

If I copy paste the url in curl_init($url ) under single quotes, everthing works.

But when I encode the url and put it in XML and decode back and put it in curl_init($url ), it does not work.

When I echo the decoded $url (see above) then I get the correct url list displayed. What am I doing wrong ?
I read closely related posts, but could not solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `&` for the sake of example.

If you want a `&` in the data of a URL (as opposed to indicating the start of a new query string key/pair). Then you need to URL encode it (as `%26`) before adding it to the URL.

If you want a `&` in the data of an XML document (e.g. if the data is a URL with a query string) then you need to XML encode it (as `&amp;`). You should be constructing the XML with an XML library (and not string bashing or templating) and the library will take care of it for you.

You should **not** have to `urldecode` data you take out of XML before using it as a URL.

Comment: No success yet. I added the XML file above. I used a converter to change the & to XML code. I tried NOT using urldecode, but no success yet. If I copy paste the echoed $url in curl_init everything works.

Comment: You should not need urldecode for that. I suspect you might have whitespace surrounding the URL in the data.

Comment: Yes, you got it. In my XML I wrote <url>, the url, and </url> on three separate lines, this caused white spaces for the url. Once I kept all of them <url>url_link</url> in one line everything worked. Thanks a lot! PS: I wanted to keep url on separate line for clarity and easy copy paste (in emacs).